Having Trouble Decrypting Drive and Reading Files
I am doing a fresh install of Linux Mint and I want to decrypt my hard drive which was encrypted during a previous installation of Mint so that I can recover some files. I have located the hdd with all of the data on the new Mint installation, and I have found the .Private and .ecryptfs directories. The recommended step to begin decrypting the data was entering the .ecryptfs directory in the terminal where the encryption related files such as wrapped-passphrase are and running sudo ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase wrapped-passphrase. I did this, entered my login password when prompted for the passphrase (I was very careful about typing the password correctly) and I got the following output:
Passphrase: 
Error: Unwrapping passphrase failed [-5]
Info: Check the system log for more information from libecryptfs

I have tried other passwords, with no success. I am using the same username and password with the new Mint installation as with the old one. An interesting difference to other cases I've read in forums is that I cannot access the folder containing the wrapped-passphrase file as a root user, but only as a normal user, so I wonder if that has anything to do with why I'm encountering this issue.
Most forum posts about this issue where the user has already tried sudo ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase wrapped-passphrase and gotten the same output as I did seemed to be resolved when they tried the command: ecryptfs-recover-private /media/mint/<drivename>/.ecryptfs/<user>/.Private. This allows the user to read and copy files without the need for a passphrase, but when I tried it, it returned this. So now I'm really stuck, and I would greatly appreciate any advice as I would really like to recover the data on this drive.
Thank you!

...check the system log? journalctl? dmesg?

I repaired the file system in the disks app and then I was able to access everything on the hard drive using ecryptfs-recover-private.
